# Is there any Terraform code or ARM Template code available for creating Action group with action as Logic app in azure

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-resource-manager, terraform-provider-azure

I am able to create action group manually in the azure portal.

I need to automate creation of Action group with action as "Logic app" in azure with the code,
Is there any terraform code or ARM template available to create action group

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create action group using both ARM template and Terraform .

**Using Terraform:**

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "monitoring-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_monitor_action_group" "example" {
  name                = "CriticalAlertsAction"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  short_name          = "p0action"

  arm_role_receiver {
    name                    = "armroleaction"
    role_id                 = "de139f84-1756-47ae-9be6-808fbbe84772"
    use_common_alert_schema = true
  }

  automation_runbook_receiver {
    name                    = "action_name_1"
    automation_account_id   = "/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourcegroups/rg-runbooks/providers/microsoft.automation/automationaccounts/aaa001"
    runbook_name            = "my runbook"
    webhook_resource_id     = "/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourcegroups/rg-runbooks/providers/microsoft.automation/automationaccounts/aaa001/webhooks/webhook_alert"
    is_global_runbook       = true
    service_uri             = "https://s13events.azure-automation.net/webhooks?token=randomtoken"
    use_common_alert_schema = true
  }

  azure_app_push_receiver {
    name          = "pushtoadmin"
    email_address = "admin@contoso.com"
  }

  azure_function_receiver {
    name                     = "funcaction"
    function_app_resource_id = "/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/rg-funcapp/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/funcapp"
    function_name            = "myfunc"
    http_trigger_url         = "https://example.com/trigger"
    use_common_alert_schema  = true
  }

  email_receiver {
    name          = "sendtoadmin"
    email_address = "admin@contoso.com"
  }

  email_receiver {
    name                    = "sendtodevops"
    email_address           = "devops@contoso.com"
    use_common_alert_schema = true
  }

  itsm_receiver {
    name                 = "createorupdateticket"
    workspace_id         = "6eee3a18-aac3-40e4-b98e-1f309f329816"
    connection_id        = "53de6956-42b4-41ba-be3c-b154cdf17b13"
    ticket_configuration = "{}"
    region               = "southcentralus"
  }

  logic_app_receiver {
    name                    = "logicappaction"
    resource_id             = "/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/rg-logicapp/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/logicapp"
    callback_url            = "https://logicapptriggerurl/..."
    use_common_alert_schema = true
  }

  sms_receiver {
    name         = "oncallmsg"
    country_code = "1"
    phone_number = "1231231234"
  }

  voice_receiver {
    name         = "remotesupport"
    country_code = "86"
    phone_number = "13888888888"
  }

  webhook_receiver {
    name                    = "callmyapiaswell"
    service_uri             = "http://example.com/alert"
    use_common_alert_schema = true
  }
}
```

**Reference:**  [monitor_action_group](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/monitor_action_group)

**Using ARM Template:**

You can refer this [template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/demos/monitor-action-groups) in GitHub.

Comment: Thnak you @AnsumanBal-MT